# UpdateButton error Array to string conversion, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I click the update button from my editoffice.blade.php this shows

"Array to string conversion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\editoffice.blade.php)"

editoffice.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', ['id' => $id, 'office_id' => $office->id]], 'class' => 'form')) !!}
```

this is where the error points to.. How to fix this?

error screenshot
[image]

THE RESULT WHEN I USE dd($request->all()); in update function

[image: dd($request->all());]

Routes

```
  Route::get('/', 'BuildingController@index')->name('index');

Route::get('building/{id}', 'PageController@show')->name('building');

Route::get('office/{id}', 'OfficeController@show')->name('officeMenu');

Route::get('offices', 'OfficeController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

  Route::get('buildings/create', 'BuildingController@create')->name('createbform');

  Route::post('building/create/store', 'BuildingController@saveBuilding')->name('createbuilding');

  Route::get('building/{id}/edit', 'BuildingController@edit');

  Route::post('building/{id}/edit', 'BuildingController@update')->name('editbuilding');

  Route::get('building/{id}/delete', 'BuildingController@destroy');

  Route::get('building/{id}/offices/create', 'OfficeController@create')->name('createofficeform');

  Route::post('building/{id}/offices/create/store', 'OfficeController@store')->name('createoffice');

Route::get('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@edit')->name('editofficeform');

Route::post('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@update')->name('editoffice');


  Route::get('offices/{id}/delete', 'OfficeController@destroy')->name('deleteoffice');
});
```

Comment: are you sure that your `$office->id` return an integer ?

Comment: What do you mean @Imran

Comment: can you please add the screen shot for the error ?

Comment: Screenshot there @rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this as i think you have wrong syntax for form

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['login', 'id' => $id, 'office_id' => $office->id], 'class' => 'form')) !!}
```

And Create the routes regarding your use

Comment: I tried this before I used this `{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', 'id' => $id, 'office_id' => $office->id], 'class' => 'form')) !!}` and used `dd($office); `  in the update function and it shows null @rahul

Comment: ok ,this will pass id and office_id in url get method and also use dd($request->all()) if you are using Request

Comment: Look at the result of request all screenshot @rahul

Comment: There the routes @rahul

Comment: then $id and $office_id.. must be passed as parameters in function edit($id,$office_id) or update($id,$office_id) if yes ,,,echo $id and $office_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162983/discussion-between-rahul-and-teamplar-jarj).